# Export data family instance constructor

Tags: haskell, export, type-families

How can I export the constructors of my data family instances? I've tried various ways without success (see commented out code):

```
module Test (
    --Foo () (..)
    --type Foo () (..)
    --UnitBar
) where

class Foo a where
    data Bar a :: *

instance Foo () where
    data Bar () = UnitBar
```

---

The only way I've been able to successfuly export the constructor is when doing a

`module Test where`

Notice the absense of parentheses. The drawback of this approach is that too much information leaves!

Comment: try `module Test ( Bar (..) ) where`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
module Test (
    Bar(..)
) where
```

to export all constructors from the associated data family `Bar`. Or

```
module Test (
    Bar(UnitBar)
) where
```

to only export the single constructor.

You can read the [relevant section in GHC's documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/type-families.html#data-family-import-export) for more details.